# Conditional moving calculations in dolphindb

Tags: dolphindb

I have a table with price and volume information. For each stock and at each timestamp, I would like to calculate the sum of volume only for those rows in the last 60 rows with price>current price. It is like the `msum` function in dolphindb with a conditional filter. I tried to use the `moving` template function in dolphindb but still couldn't come up with a solution. Is there a way to do it in dolphindb?

Answer (score 0):

This example should help. It uses the higher order function `moving` in dolphindb. It is not as fast as the moving window functions such as `msum` but can get the job done.

```
t=table(09:30:00 + (0..59)*60 as time, (1..20) join (20..1) join (1..20) as x, rand(10.0, 60) as y)

f = def(x,y){return sum(y[x>x.tail()])}
select time, x, y, moving(f, [x, y], 10) from t
```